# Maven creates 2 archive files

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am using Maven to build my project.  It was working fine up until I put in a parent pom.  Now, the project still builds but the output is 2 jar files instead of one.  One of them ends in a `-boot.jar`, and seems to be the correct jar file, because it has all the dependencies baked in and is over 60mb.  The other file has the correct name (`projectId-version.jar`) but is less than 1mb, and this is the one that gets picked up by the pipeline process, and it fails deployment.

I need mvn to build just one jar with all the dependencies baked in.

I am using Spring boot 1.5.19 (the parent pom has this dependency).  Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the minimal snippets of both your pom files to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the documentation of the spring boot maven plugin usage and docuemtation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html

Specifically the `repackage` goal. The parent POM you are using must be configured to set the new artifact to add the `boot.jar` via the `classifier` configuration.

> Classifier to add to the repackaged archive. If not given, the main artifact will be replaced by the repackaged archive. If given, the classifier will also be used to determine the source archive to repackage: if an artifact with that classifier already exists, it will be used as source and replaced. If no such artifact exists, the main artifact will be used as source and the repackaged archive will be attached as a supplemental artifact with that classifier. Attaching the artifact allows to deploy it alongside to the original one,

You could define the configuration settings for the maven plugin and override whatever is defined in the parent.

```
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier></classifier>
                </configuration>      
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  I did have to add an id to the execution, like so:
`<id>repackage</id>`

Comment: Another thing I had to add was `<layout>JAR</layout>` in the configuration, this creates a proper layout which can be executed via `java -jar`